# Mixing @ResponseStatus on our own Exceptions and handling other Exceptions in @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I was reading this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#what-to-use-when) on Exception handling in Spring MVC and in
"what to use When "  section of that blog, it mentions

> - For exceptions you write, consider adding @ResponseStatus to them.
> - For all other exceptions implement an @ExceptionHandler method on a      @ControllerAdvice class or use an instance of
>   SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. You may well have
>   SimpleMappingExceptionResolver configured for your application
>   already, in which case it may be easier to add new exception classes
>   to it than implement a @ControllerAdvice.

Is there any good reason why we should not put all handling in @controlleradvice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For example if you would write your own exception for NotFound - which is pretty self-explanatory, you don't have to add anything extra to this exception, writing a handler for it is overkill - you can just add a @ResponseStatus to it place some info like (value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Not found") which if fixed and be done with it.

Now for exceptions which require logging or require more control over the text - e.g. internationalization you will write it in the handler.

Think they were just trying to avoid the handler overkill for places where it can be handled with one line extra.